# Firebase Invitations Error - Link not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-invites

I'm trying to get Firebase invitations working. I've followed the instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/android).

The code that fires off the invitation process is as follows

```
        AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder intentBuilder = new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder(LanguageManager.getString("title-Invitation"))
                .setMessage(LanguageManager.formatString("message-INVITATION_{game-name}", ScribbleGame.getGame().getDisplayName()))
                .setEmailSubject(LanguageManager.formatString("title-TRY_{game_name}", ScribbleGame.getGame().getDisplayName()))
                .setEmailHtmlContent(emailHtml);

        application.startActivityForResult(intentBuilder.build(), ActivityResultConstants.REQUEST_INVITE);
```

The email contains a link inserted using the `%%APPINVITE_LINK_PLACEHOLDER%%` tag. The invitations are sent as expected.

I've tried both with and without deep links. Without deep links, I get a URL like this, which doesn't work and returns a 404 error.

https://plus.google.com/appinvite/131189621476-3ec41294-23ea-47e7-81d7-9a5fd004de6e

With deep links, I get a URL like this, which doesn't work and returns a 500 error.

https://sfqj5.app.goo.gl/i/131189621476-b6d8a1cf-81b4-4318-90d0-c32ee1a945e1

I've done a lot of digging but have failed to establish why the links aren't working.

Comment: I got the same 404 error as you. Have you found any solutions for it?

Comment: @SamLu No solution found I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have to set deep link while build invitation intent. I use default link, which I got from firebase console.

[cant upload screenshot for some reason, so it's link to imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dprur.jpg)

Comment: In the question it says "With deep links, I get a URL like this, which doesn't work and returns a 500 error."

Comment: @Will Calderwood, I found this question while try without deepLink as I get 404 as mentioned in question. So my answers solves case with no deepLink only. I dont now reason of error in second case, but for me this answer is useful

Comment: May be there is issue with not setting SHA in console or not updated google-services.json or your app doesnt  released in PlayMarket

Answer (score 1):

I got the same 404 error and finally fix it by calling `AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder.setDeepLink()`.

For details, please visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/android

Even you are using play-services-appinvite, you still have to add your project to Firebase and get the deeplink uri from firebase console. Following step 1, 2 and 3 of "Before you begin", it works for my apps.

Answer (score 0):

Put `setDeepLink()` method in Intent builder. It solved my error.

```
val intent = AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder(getString(R.string.invite_friends_title))
                                .setMessage(getString(R.string.invite_friends_message))
                                .setDeepLink(Uri.parse("https://"))
                                .setOtherPlatformsTargetApplication(
                                        AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder.PlatformMode.PROJECT_PLATFORM_IOS,
                                        "311303977939-11h8u454au9q1ts1mleiat83v2r2cd5n.apps.googleusercontent.com")
                                .build()
```

Comment: please add your problem!

Comment: Nice that you are to help and contribute. Please refer once [Code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on stackoverflow to do best.